# How to test the equality of two proportions with multiple samplings?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, proportion

I am searching for a statistical test to compare two proportions of responsive cells.
I know that Khi2, z-test and Fisher’s exact test allow this kind of comparison but the issue I have is that I have several proportions in each cases (ie : several samples on the same condition that all contain a proportion).

For example:
Drug A = [12/25, 1/100, 40/70]
Drug B = [17/35, 40/200, 20/50]

I suppose that I cannot use a t-test because the data is discrete (1 if the cell respond, 0 if it does not).
I also does not want to do the mean of my data because I want to consider the variation between each measures.
Should I use a GLM with a Bernoulli law or something like that?

Comment: First, we should discuss how drug A can give obviously incompatible $12/25, 1/100,$ and $40/70.$ Different kinds of groups? Different dosages?

Comment: Let's say It's 3 replicates of cell cultures treated with drug A and 3 others treated with drug B. So in the case of drug A, the first culture contain 25 cells among which 12 are responsive.